# How to create textures with offsets from mesh edge?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, texture-coordinates, dynamic

I have the outline of a building that, when intersected by a Boolean, I want to show the interior texture with several layers of materials. This would show a layer of plaster, a layer of brick, and a layer of render. The brick would be, say 10cm from one edge and 5cm from the other edge, with the other two textures filling the gaps.

I can get the interior face to show a texture, that's easy. But, I am having difficulty setting up the offset from the edge *and* combining multiple textures with offsets to edges. I cant seem to get anything to work with the texture coordinates and mapping nodes, is this even possible?

Images for reference:

This is visually what I want to achieve, with each layer in red offset from the interior and exterior wall, meaning it follows corners and other angles:

[image: Here is what I want to achieve]

Here is one of my attempts, the red shows that the offset is only following one axis, rather than the edge of the mesh:
[image: Here is one of my attempts, the red shows that the offset is only following one axis, rather than the edge of the mesh]

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QO9tUMazKljAAwAplQ1lEoN6dzSTsXXr/view?usp=drive_link).

Comment: Are there reference images that you can share? Also pics of your own model.

Comment: @Akshay2005, sure, updated the post to add those details :)